# PDFBox doesn't show correct validating PDF digital signature after it was modified

Tags: pdf, pdfbox, digital-signature

Currently I'm working on PDFBox library to provide digital signature solution. My problem is detecting the pdf that has been modified. On Adobe Reader can detect this modification but on PDFBox it doesn't detect the document has been modified (I've using CoverWholeDocument method to detect the signature). The same case on DSS Europe doesn't give the give correct validation (https://ec.europa.eu/cefdigital/DSS/webapp-demo/validation)
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/103DsxKzYxp2UMV_AP0bFxI-YXXE6kuQV/view?usp=sharing) *modified pdf*

Does anyone can help this problem using PDFBox how to detect this signature is invalid?

Comment: I downloaded your example PDF, but Adobe Reader does not mention a "modification" but that "There are errors in the formatting or information contained in this signature." DSS also considers your signature as "not intact." Did you probably attach the wrong PDF?

Comment: The PDFBox example `ShowSignature` also says "Signature verification failed". So I don't see a difference between the three approaches you mentioned.

Comment: Im sorry, im wrong attaching the pdf file. This the real document [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/103DsxKzYxp2UMV_AP0bFxI-YXXE6kuQV/view?usp=sharing) _modified pdf_

Comment: In your new document the PDFBox example `ShowSignature` does show "Signature does not cover whole document", so PDFBox indicates that there are changes added in an incremental update. (It does not analyze whether these changes are allowed or not, PDFBox does not support validation at that level out of the box.)

Comment: eSig DSS for your new document shows "Signature scope:
Partial PDF (PARTIAL)", so DSS indicates that there are changes added in an incremental update. (It does not analyze whether these changes are allowed or not, eSig DSS does not support validation at that level out of the box.) So I don't see a difference between the three approaches here either.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I'll update the question to include the updated link. For the solution how can I do for now using the PDFBox?

Comment: Well, your problem cannot be reproduced - Adobe Acrobat, PDFBox, and eSig DSS did not contradict each other. So you should really clarify what you're looking for.

Comment: Be aware that `ShowSignature.java` is an example. It talks a lot, and among many things here: "Signature does not cover whole document". You need to modify the code to fail in the way you like (e.g. throw an exception).

Comment: Well, I see thanks mkl and @TilmanHausherr for your information. So I need to modify the code ShowSignature.java to show validation information just like Adobe.

Comment: ShowSignature does show a lot of validation information. What it doesn't do is to make a difference between allowed and forbidden incremental changes. "Signature does not cover whole document" just tells that changes were made. For a contract, you don't want this. But for a fillable form, certain changes (filled fields) would be OK.

Comment: Okey @tilmanhausherr thanks for your enlightening. I would like to say thanks to you and the other contributors that I can't say one by one for the great open source tools PDFBox. Someday I hope can be contributors too to make the PDFBox more great and robust . Would you share the fundamentals reference of PDF that newbie like me step by step can learn how to create and securing PDF file?

Comment: The best is to look at the examples in the PDFBox source code download. And the PDF specification: https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf

Comment: Thanks @tilmanhausherr for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the detection of modifications occurred within internal PDF objects between signed and final PDF document revisions has been introduced in DSS 5.10 : see [documentation](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html#_object_modification_detection).
If you try to validate the attached document with the last major version of DSS (including the [demo](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation)) it returns the corresponding warning message:

> The document contains undefined object modifications after the signature revision!

Unfortunately, software cannot be certain about the origin of a change (whether it is expected change or not), therefore it is always recommended to verify the document manually after obtaining such an error.

Please also note, that the validation level of objects modification may be enforced to fail the signature validation, instead of logging a warning. For that you may use `<UndefinedChanges Level="FAIL">` element within the [validation policy](https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html#validationPolicy).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is there any best practice to implement validation just like Adobe does to detect illegal modification after the document signed?

Comment: Adobe's algorithm is a secret and unfortunately they don't disclose how it works. The best solution for you, probably, will be to use DSS, that performs validation checks based on visual comparison of the signed document and based on checking the modification within internal PDF objects.

Comment: For your information, ETSI is currently working on a new standard describing the best practices for identifying different kind of attacks on electronic signatures. When the standards will be available in public, DSS is going to include those algorithms within its own implementation.